# c# add page to onenote from template

Tags: c#, programmatically-created, onenote

New to OneNote development.  I have an app that I want to add a new page based on the template that is the default in this section of my notebook.

I want to take some text from a textbox and name the generated new page to that text.  I don't need to do anything else with the page from the app   Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Onenote API to programmatically recall the template page's content as html  See http://dev.onenote.com/docs#/reference/get-pages/v10menotespagesidcontentincludeids on how to do this.

Once you have the template's html, you can make the title tag with the title you get from your web form . eg:  my title  and make a POST request to the section. See http://dev.onenote.com/docs#/reference/post-pages/v10menotessectionsidpages

That should take care of it.